# Google App Engine and Shared Google Spreadshhet

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have  project that is coming along nicely.  I can now read and edit my Google spreadsheet using my Google App Engine App. I set up sharing in the spreadsheet giving edit permissions to myapplicaton@appspot.gserviceaccount.com

If everything works as I hope I will someday get customers that will be able to also share their spreadsheets and will be able read and edit their spreadsheets using my application.

I can see in the Google App Engine Logs which spreadsheets are being accessed using my program but I was hoping for a little more.

Is there a way for me to know all of the spreadsheets that have given my application permission to edit them?

Is there a way to refuse edit shares if I find out that one of these spreadsheets is abusing my application's terms of use etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using the drive api you can see files shared with you. But it seems you only care for people abusing your system and those you already detect since they have to go through your appengine frontend.

Comment: Zig thanks for the reply. I think it would be nice to be able to see all of the files that are shared with the app engine application.  It would also be nice to delete a file; break the sharing connection, if it is determined that someone shared it for reasons that are not appropriate. I will look at the drive API.  I am also thinking about the appengine logs, the doc app script and my py code. I want to give domain admins some sort of document inventory so that they can review their companies documents at any time to determine if they are appropriate for their organization.